# Proper way to assign KeyValuePair from two arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net

My array:

```
string[] name = "a,b,c,d".Split(',');//key
string[] path = "w,x,y,z".Split(',');//value
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

I try to assign a value like this.

```
foreach (string s in name)
{
    foreach (string sp in path)
    {
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s, sp));
    }
}
```

But my logic is fail. What is a proper way to assign a KeyValue pair from two arrays?

Expected outcome.

```
a-w
b-x
c-y
d-z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the same loop for both arrays (or use the LINQ solutions proposed in other answers):

```
string[] name = "a,b,c,d".Split(','); // Key
string[] path = "w,x,y,z".Split(','); // Value
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < name.Length, i++)
{
    if (i == path.Length) // In case both arrays are not the same length
    {
        break;
    }
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(name[i], path[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
string[] names = "a,b,c,d".Split(','); //key
string[] paths = "w,x,y,z".Split(','); //value

var namesAndPaths = names.Zip(paths, (name, path) => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(name, path));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are **sure** that both `array`s are equal length, you can do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < name.Length; ++i) {
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(name[i], path[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using LINQ:

```
var mergedKeyValues = name.Select((n,i) => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(n,path[i]))
                             .ToList();
```

**Output**

```
   [a, w]
   ,
   [b, x]
   ,
   [c, y]
   ,
   [d, z]
```

Check out [this demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DlbIFE).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both arrays will be of same length you can do this -

```
for(int i=0; i<name.Length; i++)
{
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(name[i], path[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a LINQ one-liner:

```
var d = name.Select((n, idx) => new { Name = n, Index = idx })
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => path[v.Index]);
```

The key here is to use the index from the `Select` method to determine the index to use in the other array.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] name = "a,b,c,d".Split(','); //key
string[] path = "w,x,y,z".Split(','); //value
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < path.Length; j++)
    {
        if (i == j)
        {
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(name[i], path[j]));
        }
    }
}
```